# OS X: respond to new audio device

Tags: macos, core-audio, iokit

I need to be notified, when a new audio device appears on OS X. I'm not sure where to start. Can Core Audio do this for me, or do I need to get down to a lower level with for instance IO Kit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by observing `kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices`. The code looks roughly like:

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = {
        .mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices,
        .mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        .mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
    };

OSStatus result = AudioObjectAddPropertyListener(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAddress, myAudioObjectPropertyListenerProc, NULL);
```

In `myAudioObjectPropertyListenerProc` you can determine what devices are currently available.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for this answer quite a while back! And btw - big fan of Max! ;)